# add a "Zoom in" button to the SharePoint page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I will need to add a button to a SharePoint 2013 page for people to zoom in a page. i used the following code

```
<button onclick="body.style.zoom='300%'">Zoom 300%</button>
<button onclick="body.style.zoom='200%'">Zoom 200%</button>
<button onclick="body.style.zoom='100%'">Zoom 100%</button>
```

it worked well, but one issue I had was that, one second after the page was zoomed in, the page got auto refreshed but the page size was reset to the original size. Can you please give me an idea how to stop the auto refresh? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add the type='button' in the button tag.

```
<button type="button" onclick="body.style.zoom='300%'">Zoom 300%</button>
<button type="button" onclick="body.style.zoom='200%'">Zoom 200%</button>
<button type="button" onclick="body.style.zoom='100%'">Zoom 100%</button>
```